# How to select a certain percentile of data in pandas DataFrame or Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame or Series with all numerical values. I want to select the top 99% values in a certain column of the DataFrame or Series and thus remove the bottom 1% smallest values. How should I realize this in Python 3? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `np.percentile`, but be careful. There is more than one definition of percentile, so make sure first this suits your needs.

Below example filters out smallest 20% values of a series.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))

# 0    0.477326
# 1    0.474181
# 2    0.438678
# 3    0.397124
# 4    0.777874
# 5    0.698927
# 6    0.244970
# 7    0.540653
# 8    0.658190
# 9    0.774246
# dtype: float64

t = s[s > np.percentile(s, 20)]

# 0    0.477326
# 1    0.474181
# 2    0.438678
# 4    0.777874
# 5    0.698927
# 7    0.540653
# 8    0.658190
# 9    0.774246
# dtype: float64
```